# How to get content-type from request header in java?

Tags: javascript, java

This problem has ruined three days of my life. Here is what I'm doing:

```
boolean mimef = false, notvideo=false;
Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
    String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
    String value = request.getHeader(key);

    System.out.println("K: "+key+" V: "+value);

    if(key.equals("content-type")){
        mimef=true;
        System.out.println("V: "+value);
        if(!value.contains("video/")){
            notvideo=true;
        }
    }
}

if(notvideo){
    System.out.println("file is not video!");
    response.setStatus(400);
    out.print("Selected file is not video, Please try again. ( '_' )");
    out.close();
    return;
}

if(!mimef){
    response.setStatus(400);
    out.print("Couldn't identify file type, Please try again ( '_' )");
    out.close();
    System.out.println("error here");
    return;
}
```

So Basically I'm using this to get `content-type` of an uploading file from post header. which it works with `.exe` and `video types` but not with pdf files, well to honest I have two .exe file which with one it works and with the other doesn't and by printing both header content-type it both says `application`, So far I could find is that with the files it doesn't work in my server console it prints `file is not video!` but in my client I never receive the error i'm suppose to.

Front-End:

```
var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
var started_at = new Date();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var sres=xhr.responseText;
        alert(sres);
    }
}
xhr.open('post','../uploadtostack',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Name',file.name);
xhr.setRequestHeader('x-File-Size',file.size);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-File-Type',file.type);
xhr.send(file);
```

---

And I also tried:

```
String contenttype = request.getContentType();
System.out.println("CT: "+contenttype);
if(!contenttype.contains("video/")){
    out.print("File is not a video, try again!");
    return;
}
```

and my console output was:

```
CT: application/pdf
CT: application/pdf
CT: application/pdf
CT: application/pdf
CT: application/pdf
CT: application/pdf
CT: application/pdf
```

I suppose the post is sent 7 times.

Comment: At which line of code is it not behaving as expected?  Did you try just getting request.getContentType() ?  Are you debugging through your code to see what is what?

Comment: Hey @BradleyD I just update my question. could read that last part, and thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Your code is hard to follow.  Exactly which lines of code in your original post are you replacing with the update you've posted?

Comment: I have putted `String contenttype = request.getContentType(); and the rest I had in my question update` just right before `boolean mimef = false, notvideo=false;`

Comment: If you're uploading/processing a .pdf file, then application/pdf is the expected/correct content-type.  http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm